# Ant patterns configuration

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have this Spring configuration and OAuth2:

```
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";
    private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
    private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";
    private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/api/**";
    private static final String PUBLIC_PATTERN = "/api/*/public/**";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                    .anonymous()
                .and()
                    .requestMatchers()
                        .antMatchers(SECURED_PATTERN)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_PATTERN).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SECURED_PATTERN).access(SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE)
                .anyRequest().access(SECURED_READ_SCOPE);
    }
}
```

Now I want to add Swagger to my project. I configured a SwaggerController:

```
@Controller //note - this is a spring-boot controller, not @RestController
public class SwaggerController {

    public static final String SWAGGER_URL = "/api/v1/public/swagger/docs";
    public static final String SWAGGER_HTML = "/swagger-ui.html";

    @RequestMapping(SWAGGER_URL)
    public String home() {
        return "redirect:" + SWAGGER_HTML;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot make the "/swagger-ui.html" path not to trigger the Spring Login.
I tried this (note that I added antMatchers for the Swagger html):

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                ...
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                        .antMatchers(PUBLIC_PATTERN).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.htm").permitAll()// No authentication
```

...
        }

But it did not work.
How do I need to configure the HttpSecurity?

Answer (score 0):

So the swagger home page should redirect to `/swagger-ui.html` ?

If yes, you have a typo when configuring `HttpSecurity`, which you only type **htm** only. So change to :

```
 .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
```

On the other hand , if the swagger home page is `/swagger-ui.htm` . Then you change the `SWAGGER_HTML` in your controller to :

```
 public static final String SWAGGER_HTML = "/swagger-ui.htm";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this override:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(SWAGGER_URL)
            .antMatchers(SWAGGER_HTML);
}
```